# Why is the symmetry of an equilateral triangle D3 and not D3h?

Tags: group-theory

On [this wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group_of_order_6), it is explained that the symmetry of an equilateral triangle is $D_3$; the equilateral triangle is symmetric under the operations of $D_3$. The operations for $D_{3h}$ symmetry are the same, except with the addition of a $\sigma_{xy}$ reflection and $2S_3$ operations. An equilateral triangle is also symmetrical under both of these latter operations as far as i can tell.

So why isnt the equilateral triangle of $D_{3h}$ symmetry? Do we not describe a form by its highest possible symmetry? If not, then by what criterion do we ascribe a symmetry group?

Comment: We are describing symmetry of an (abstract) equilateral triangle, not the symmetry of "an equilateral triangle in Euclidean 3-space".

Comment: @user10354138 what is an "abstract" equilateral triangle?

Comment: There are various ways to do this, for example, the three point metric space $\{a,b,c\}$ with the discrete metric if you want just a minimal model, or you can go full fledge with $\overline{\operatorname{conv}}\{1,\omega,\omega^2\}\subset\mathbb{C}$ ($\omega^2+\omega+1=0$) with all the structures of $\mathbb{C}$ restricted to this set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We render the symmetry of an object in the minimal space that contains it.  In two dimensions we don't have the reflection through the plane that's the "h" part of $D_{nh}$; given a regular polygon the only symmetries in the two-dimensional space that contains the polygon are those of $D_n$.

Comment: So when assigning point groups, chemists always stick to 3-D Euclidean space, while mathematicians always reduce the form to the lowest dimensional space possible?

Comment: @Blaisem No.  "Point group" specifically refers to a group of symmetries of Euclidean space, rather than of a geometric object--although chemists might be more likely to assume 3-D Euclidean space and mathematicians might insist that you specify which dimension.  But your fundamental problem is that the action of $D_{3h}$ on an equilateral triangle isn't faithful.  If you want to get $D_{3h}$ as the group of symmetries of an object, specify an equilateral triangular prism (along with the origin along its axis, to eliminate translations) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Because the action of $D_{3h}$ on 3-space induces an epimorphism of $D_{3h}$ onto $D_3$ that sends $\sigma_{xy}$ to the identity, since $\sigma_{xy}$ sends each point of the triangle to itself.  *Any* covering of $D_3$ can act on the equilateral triangle and produce all its symmetries, and no other groups can.  That's what makes $D_3$ its symmetry group.

If you want to get $D_{3h}$ as a group of symmetries of a geometric object, specify an equilateral triangular prism plus a point on its axis instead of an equilateral triangle.

I should also point out that even in 3-D Euclidean space the point group $D_3$ is of independent interest, as several space groups have $D_3$ as their underlying point group.

Comment: One geometric object with $D_3$ symmetry is the most highly symmetric form for a pentagonal 18-h e d r o n.  Take each face of a triangular bipyramid and draw a ray from the centroid parallel to each side, making a pinwheel.  Do the same with the other faces making all the pinwheels chiral in the same sense.  The result is graphically equivalent to the claimed polyhedron and with the chirality, it has $D_3$ symmetry.